# Euclid Numbers (proof without calculator)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am confused as to how to show that Euclid numbers are not primes without use of a calculator. I know the 6th Euclid number is not prime, but I don't know how it would be possible to reach this conclusion without a decent amount of work in first verifying previous numbers are prime and then bashing it out to $(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13)+1$ and taking it mod every prime from 13 to 59 before seeing that it isn't prime. Is there some insight I'm missing for reaching a counter example to show $$p_1p_2\dots p_n+1$$ is not prime?

Work so far:
I can verify $e_1 = 3$, $e_2 = 7$, $e_3 = 31$, $e_4 = 211$ and show each is prime, but once I get to $e_5$ it seems like the work for showing that it is prime and then moving to $e_6$ would be a lot. Thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think there should be an easy way to decide this?

Comment: To find the list of the known such primes google "primorial"

Comment: " p#+1 is prime for primes p=2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 31, 379, 1019, 1021, 2657, 3229, 4547, 4787, 11549, 13649, 18523, 23801, 24029, and 42209, 145823, 366439 and 392113"  and it is not known whether this list is infinite